# How to split information stored in a collection - Blue Prism?

Tags: regex, string, email, blueprism

I made a process that grabs the email body in an Outlook email. The email body is stored in a collection, however it puts everything into one row (which contains multiple information). I need to grab order numbers (that contain letters and numbers) and quantity amounts from this row, but I am not sure how to go about this. I am still learning how to use Blue Prism. Any advice would be great!

[image: Checks email box if exists, then gets unread emails and stores in collection]

[image: VBO stores entire email body into a collection. Stores into one row, includes spaces and all. Tried to use the split line command to split each line of the email body collection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the data is in collection, but it's in one big text field... so it's more of a question about how to parse the text to retrieve the data. And the answer is only one! The Regular Expressions!

You can find a regex action in below object:

```
Object: Utility - Strings C#
Action: Extract Regex Values
```

The regex is really powerful tool - for example with a simple "https:\S+" you can find all the links from the email. I think it's a great tool to learn as a RPA developer.

If you'd like the community to help you with building a an exact expression, then you'll need to how the exact html of the email message.

Comment: Thank you Andrzej! I am working on building an expression with this. Making progress in this area.